# retrieving all users using google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, gdata

I got a oauth autorization also enable the api provisioning. Also added all gdata sources to my project, And still getting error

```
      UserService client = new UserService("mdeocasec");
      try {
        client.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());

      } catch (OAuthException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      URL url = null;
      try {
        url = new URL("https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/");

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      BaseFeed<UserFeed, UserEntry> userFeed = null;
      try {

       userFeed = client.getFeed(url, UserFeed.class);

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ServiceException e) {
          System.out.println("l"+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
      } 

   error here >>> List<UserEntry> userEntries = userFeed.getEntries();
```

Comment: Well, what error are you getting?  Be detailed with your questions!  It is painfully easy to provide too little information, and very hard to provide too much.

Comment: what UserService are you using? UserService in google app engine needs to be initiated by UserServiceFactory.getUserService()